# Is it possible in one PowerShell line to start Microsoft Edge with multiple tabs?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, microsoft-edge

I'd like to be able to start Microsoft Edge (Chromium) with multiple tabs via a single PowerShell command in a shortcut (not a script).  Here is what I have that works for one tab:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& start microsoft-edge:https://www.outlook.com"`

but I am unclear how to add on a set of sites.  Something like:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& start microsoft-edge:https://www.outlook.com;https://www.google.com"`

That doesn't work, but I'm looking for something along those lines.  Note, I do not have admin access to the workstation where I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, **only a *single* URL is supported when you launch via the `microsoft-edge:` protocol scheme**.

However, you can **launch Edge via the `MicrosoftEdge.exe` *executable*** located in directory `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, which ***does* accept multiple URLs** (note the need to separate them with `,` in this case):

```bash
powershell.exe "start $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe https://example.org, https://google.com"
```

The **above is short for** (note the use of the `-Command` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter and the use of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s full name and parameter names):

```bash
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -FilePath $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe -ArgumentList https://example.org, https://google.com"
```

---

In fact, with an executable-based invocation **you don't even need `Start-Process`** in this case, given that a *GUI* executable launches *asynchronously* even with *direct* invocation:

```bash
powershell.exe "& $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe https://example.org https://google.com"
```

Note the need to use `&`, because the executable path contains a variable reference, and that the two URLs are now *space*-separated (passed as individual arguments).

---

Conversely, if you wanted to *wait* for Edge to close again before returning from the call, you would *normally* use `Start-Process -Wait`, but this is *not* effective with AppX applications such as Microsoft Edge, unfortunately, at least as of PowerShell 7.3.3 - see [GitHub issue #10996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996).

Comment: Works great and a lot of helpful context, thank you.