# Open multiple files as tab group in Microsoft edge using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I know how to open (multiple) tabs in microsoft edge [using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006821/is-it-possible-in-one-powershell-line-to-start-microsoft-edge-with-multiple-tabs), but I need to open them as a tab group.
In the end I need to create multiple groups of several files. I would be open to use a different browser like Chrome or Firefox but Edge is preferred.
Is there some solution using tools like Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Edge/Chrome currently does not have such a command line option to create tab groups/open tabs as a tab group. So, PowerShell won't work.

As to Selenium, there's no such API to interact with tab groups. Also, no keyboard shortcut for tab groups. As far as I'm concerned, you'll have to add tabs to tab groups via browser UI.